# I need some C# generics clarification

Tags: c#, class, object, generics, abstract

I have a little problem over here. I am using a generic class but I do not know the type before the selection from the UI pannel. How can I declare my object before knowing what type it will have?
So here is the sample

```
public class UI
{
    Agent myAgent;
    public UI()
    {
    }
    public void Initialize()
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "LabAgent")
            myAgent = new Agent<LabState, LabAction>();
        else
            myAgent = new Agent<FieldState, FieldAction>();
    }
}
```

The Agent class is a simple generic class. How can I make something like this, but to actually work? How to define the myAgent without knowing the type?
Note: I use C#, not Java.
edit 1:

```
public class Agent<S,A>
    where S : AState
    where A : AAction
{
    private List<S> states;
    private List<A> actions;

    private Dictionary<KeyValuePair<S, A>, float> Q;

    private S stareCurenta;

    public void Initializare()
    {
        foreach (S s in states)
        {
            foreach (A a in actions)
            {
                Q.Add(new KeyValuePair<S, A>(s, a), 32000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could accomplish that with an interface and covariance, but that should only be used if the types are used in a read only fashion in the `Agent` class.

Comment: `KeyValuePair` is not a good candidate to use as the key in a dictionary.  You might want to use `Tuple<S, A>` instead.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Didn't use Tuple as far. Could you please explain a little the difference between the two of them?

Comment: `Tuple` is simply meant to represent a combination of n separate objects where as `KeyValuePair` is meant to specifically represent a combination of a key and a value.

Comment: Based on your update I don't see how `states` or `actions` will ever be populated and thus `Initializare` doesn't really do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to use co-variance.  In order to do that first you need an interface that `Agent` would implement, let's call it `IAgent`.  Then you need to define that interface like

```
public interface IAgent<out TState, out TAction> 
    where TState : IState
    where TAction : IAction
```

Then you could do

```
IAgent<IState, IAction> agent = new Agent<LabState, LabAction>
```

Assuming that your `Agent`, `LabState`, and `LabAction` implement `IAgent`, `IState`, and `IAction` respectively.  But then you'd only define `IAgent` as co-variant if it only returns values of those types and never takes them.  So the generic types should only show up as the return type of methods and as the type of read only properties.  You could also substitute base classes for the interfaces `IAction` and `IState`, but the co-variance operator `out` will only work with an interface.

Comment: Actually, my LabState and LabAction do something like this. I have an abstract class AState and an abstract class AAction. And LabState extends AState, LabAction extends AAction. Check my last coment at the above answer, explained what I kind of tried.

Answer (score 6):

> How to define the myAgent without knowing the type?

You can't.  `Agent<LabState, LabAction>` and `Agent<FieldAgent, FieldAction>` are completely different types.  If you tried to use `myAgent` in another method, how would you know at compile-time if it was an `Agent<LabState, LabAction>` or an `Agent<FieldAgent, FieldAction>` and thus how could the compiler bind to any properties or methods?

You *could* have a non-generic `Agent` base class, but it would not have access to any of the generic properties or methods.

Comment: Sorry. It is LabState, FieldState. And LabAction, FieldAction.

Comment: LabState and FieldState extend AState (AState is an abstract class).

Comment: It doesn't matter. The fact is that types with different generic parameters are different types.  There's _some_ connection in the type system, but there's not an automatic base type that both can be assigned to.

Comment: OK please add these details to your question, including the definitions of `Agent` and the types.  You _might_ be able to use covariance but without the definitions it's not clear.

Comment: @DStanley - You've got an extra backtick there. It's obscuring part of the answer.

Comment: I agree, although you "kind of" can, using reflection, but I guess that would defeat the purpose... Other possibility would be to define the `myAgent` field as `object` (or any other common base class), and the code would compile...

Comment: Hmm, yes, that would sort a bit the problem. Having an Object myAgent would compile. But at initialization, I would have to define the myAgent as myAgent = new Agent<...>(); Could give it a try.

Comment: If you're just using `Object` then there's no benefit to generics in the first place.

Comment: Agree. How abut if I would use an abstract class? Agent<abstractState,abstractAction>, and when I declare it, I have something like Agent<abstractState,abstractAction> myAgent = new Agent<LabState, LabAction>(); ?

Comment: @SimplyMe I see your edits, but it's still not clear how you're benefiting from generics.  You could simple declare it as `Agent<AState, AAction>` and you'd be fine from what you're posted.

Comment: I have to agree with @DStanley - unless you can benefit from it in compile time (while coding), there's no gain in using generics...

Comment: Generics help me because some `States` mix with some `Actions`. I will try and probably come back with a more precise answer tomorrow morning

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

I think you'd be better off making two UI classes, one for each type of agent, both derived from the same base class that provides all the UI non-agent functionality.

Comment: If so, the generics would be useless. I have only 2 types of states and actions, but I want to be able to add more, so if I want to do this, I need to make another UI for each new pair of state and actions? It is not quite good to reuse the code.

Comment: If all the UI instances do is create a new Agent, and all the rest of the work is done in the base UI class - it's perfectly reasonable reuse of code.

Comment: I have my UI. The UI uses a controller, the controller has a repo and the repo requires in the constructor to specify an agent (a specialised agent). So if I use generics, I can change only the type of the Agent, not the whole app.